# Javascript object destructuring/manipulation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following object:

```
const original = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}
```

and I want to create a new, distinct object with the following structure:

```
const modified = {
  first: 100,
  third: 3
}
```

ES6 syntax allows me to do some pretty powerful manipulation, like:

`const {second, ...newElement} = original`

which results in:

```
const newElement = {
  first: 1,
  third: 3
}
```

but then I would still have to do `newElement.first = 100`.

Alternatively, I could do:

`const newElement2 = Object.assign({}, original , {second: undefined, first: 100})`

but this doesn't really delete `second`, it just sets it to `undefined`.

---

Is there a more elegant alternative to go from `original` to `modified`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an object with updated `first: 100` using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), then destructure it using [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

**Note:** [Object rest/spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is a Stage 4 proposal for ECMAScript, and not part of ES6.

```js
const original = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}

const { second, ...newElement } = { ...original, first: 100 };

console.log(newElement);
```

Comment: It's a typescript typing issue, and not a linter issue, and you can find several solutions at the link.